# how to fix the error c2118: negative subscript

Tags: c++, visual-c++, 64-bit, win64

Again, porting 32-bit app to 64-bit. I get the negative subscript error on the C_ASSERT statement mentioned below..

```
C_ASSERT (sizeof(somestruct) == some#define);
```

I also read the http://support.microsoft.com/kb/68475 article but not sure if I know how to fix it in this case.

Help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `C_ASSERT`? If it is some kind of static assert, then this error would simply indicate an assertion failure. It is a relatively common way to implement static assert, making it result in a negative subscript error if the condition yields false.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm guessing the `C_ASSERT` macro is defined something like this:

```
#define C_ASSERT(x) typedef char C_ASSERT_ ## __COUNTER__ [(x) ? 1 : -1];
```

This is a compile-time assertion: if the compile-time expression `x` is true, then this expands to something like

```
typedef char C_ASSERT_1[1];
```

which declares the typename `C_ASSERT_1` to be an alias for the type `char[1]` (array of 1 `char`).  Converely, if the expression `x` is false, it expands to

```
typedef char C_ASSERT_1[-1];
```

which is a compiler error, since you can't have an array type of negative size.

Hence, your problem is that the expression `sizeof(somestruct) == some#define` is false, i.e. the size of `somestruct` is NOT what your code is expecting.  You need to fix this -- either change the size of `somestruct`, or change the value of `some#define`, making sure that this won't break anything.

Comment: Yeah..Thats right. The size of struct did not match the #define value as the struct had couple of pointers and 64 bit compilation changed the struct size. Thanks though and I figured it late sunday night and now able to compile it.